# What is an idiomatic way to non-destructively append a value to a vector?

Tags: vector, rust

I have a program in which I `fold` over a vector of strings, and increment a value and build another vector over that. Something like this:

```
struct Widget { foo: isize, text: &'static str }
let foos = vec!["a", "b", "c"];
let (final, ws) = foos.iter().fold((0, widgets), |(x, ws), text| {
    (x+1, Widget { foo: x, text: text })
});
```

The problem with the above code is that I need to *append* the new widget to `ws`, not return the new widget in place of `ws`. To do this, I need a way to non-destructively append a value to a vector. Here's the signature, roughly, of the function I'm looking for:

`fn append<T>(vec: Vec<T>, item: T) -> Vec<T>`

I can't seem to find a function like this. It seems like this (or this as a method on `Vec`) would be very idiomatic for Rust, but its just not there. Is there another way to implement this more idiomatically, or is there a function like the above?

Comment: I didn't clearly understand.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *non-destructively*?

Comment: `fold` doesn't seem like the right tool here. You should instead use `enumerate` to generate the `x` index, and `map` followed by `collect` to create the vector of widgets.

Comment: Sure! I guess I expected the function signature to explain what I meant, but I'll try to do better. Sorry!

Comment: Is it what you want? `fn append<T>(mut vs: Vec<T>, v: T) -> Vec<T> { vs.push(v); vs }`

Comment: Ah, That was the kind of answer I was looking for, interjay. I thought about doing the enumerate/map/collect thing but for some reason decided it wasn't going to work. I'll look at my actual code and try to figure out why.

Comment: It's exactly because of the function signature that I ask. You've given up control of the `Vec`, so why do you care what happens to it, destroyed or otherwise.

Comment: red75prime, that is what I wanted but I was hoping it would be a builtin. (:

Comment: I meant non-destructively as in "without mutation going on." So like the ++ operator in Haskell.

Comment: But again, *why* — red75prime's answer uses mutability (`push`), but it fits exactly with the signature you asked for. You can't *tell* that there's mutability though.

Comment: I just didn't want to deal with the mutability. I just wanted to return an expression. That's all.

Comment: This was more of a question about how to idiomatically do the above (a la interjay's answer) than about that specific function. That's why I put idiomatic in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> non-destructively append a value to a vector

This is impossible. Modifying a vector... modifies it. You can't get around that. You can choose to `clone` the vector, which avoids mutating the *original* vector. You still need to mutate the clone, however:

```
let things = vec![1];
let things2 = {
    let mut tmp = things.clone();
    tmp.push(2);
    tmp
};
```

If you are done with the original vector, you can reuse it:

```
let things = vec![1];
let things2 = {
    let mut tmp = things;
    tmp.push(2);
    tmp
};
```

This can be extracted into your desired function signature:

```
fn append(vec: Vec<i32>, item: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    let mut vec = vec;
    vec.push(item);
    vec
};
```

Which would idiomatically but equivalently be written as

```
fn append(mut vec: Vec<i32>, item: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec.push(item);
    vec
};

let things = vec![1];
let things2 = append(things.clone(), 2);
let things2 = append(things, 2);
```

> It seems like this (or this as a method on `Vec`) would be very idiomatic for Rust

Not really - to have this method signature, you have to own the `Vec`. It's more common to only have a mutable reference to the `Vec`, which offers a different set of capabilities.

There was some talk about implementing `Add` for `Vec`, which might have allowed something like `let things2 = things + 2`, but I don't know that went anywhere.

---

For what it's worth, I'd write your code as:

```
let foos = ["a", "b", "c"];

let ws: Vec<_> = foos.iter()
    .enumerate()
    .map(|(i, text)| Widget { foo: i as isize, text })
    .collect();
```